# Raphaël - SVG on top of HTML

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm making a project which uses HTML elements as nodes in a diagram and uses [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) to draw lines between them. The problem is that the lines always wind up underneath the HTML elements. I have tried

```
raphael.canvas.style.zIndex = 1000;
```

(which is larger than all my other z-indexes) and also tried placing the SVG canvas as the last element in the DOM with no luck. How can I make these lines be drawn on top?

Comment: Can you try reducing your problem down to a small example that demonstrates the problem you are having?

Comment: Or posting up a link to look at?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you ensured that your SVG element, and its containing element, are relatively or absolutely positioned? `z-index` only applies to positioned elements, not elements that have `static` (the default, in-flow) positioning.

Comment: Thanks, this was the exact problem.